# Injecting to Controller not working in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I have a `Storage` Ember object that I injected to `route` and `controller`. I can access `Storage` in `route` but not in `controller`. (Emberjs version: 1.5.1)

```
App.Storage = Ember.Object.extend
  #...
  #...

Ember.onLoad "Ember.Application", (Application)->
  Application.initializer
    name: "storage"
    initialize: (container, application)->
      application.register "storage:main", application.Storage, singleton: true

      #Inject to both controller and route
      application.inject "controller", "storage", "storage:main"
      application.inject "route", "storage", "storage:main"

#I can access `Storage` here in Route
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model)->
    console.log @get('storage')
    #OUTPUTS: Class {toString: function, __ember1397551513765: "ember299", __nextSuper: undefined, __ember1397551513765_meta: Object, constructor: function…}

#But I can't access `Storage` here in Controller
App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  actions:
    createMessage: ->
      console.log @get('storage') 
      #OUTPUTS: `undefined`
```

I also tried testing on Chrome console:

```
App.__container__.lookup('storage:main')
//OUTPUTS: Class {toString: function, __ember1397551513765: "ember299", __nextSuper: undefined, __ember1397551513765_meta: Object, constructor: function
App.__container__.lookup('route:messages').get('storage')
//OUTPUTS: Class {toString: function, __ember1397551513765: "ember299", __nextSuper: undefined, __ember1397551513765_meta: Object, constructor: function…}
App.__container__.lookup('controller:messages').get('storage')
//OUTPUTS: undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to recreate a JSBin with this behavior? Also, just for shiggles, try changing that name from `storage` to something else. There are a few undocumented reserved words/names floating around the Ember.js codebase, so let's eliminate that possibility.

Comment: Hmmm it's weird that it's working here:
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sicer/3/)

I'll check on my codes again... Do you think the version has any effect on this? in that jsbin: ember version = 1.0.0, and I'm using 1.5.1

Comment: It's not out of the realm of possibilities. The Ember team does a great job with backwards compatibility, but sometimes they miss something. If you could narrow it down to a single version, that would be great. (Also, 1.5.0 is the latest release. Are you using 1.5.0 or 1.4.1?)

Comment: oh yeah, 1.5.0 is the latest... I don't know why my rails-ember gem generated an ember.js file with something like the following at the beginning part of the file: `@version   1.5.1+pre.ff8c6bbb` Thanks! I'll check on my codes again, I might missed something :)

Comment: That version string means you're using a canary release - the most recent build of the day. Canary releases are expected to have bugs in them. You might want to try using the release version of 1.5.0 and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I can access the `storage` in the controller now. Thanks! :D